# Run tests programmatically in Go

Tags: go, testing

I have some tests that I'd like to run programmatically in Go. I'm trying to use `testing.RunTests` but it's raising a runtime error. I can't figure out what's wrong with the code either.

This is what it looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    if false {
        t.Error("This is a mocked failed test")
    }
}

func main() {
    testing.RunTests(func(pat, str string) (bool, error) { return true, nil },
        []testing.InternalTest{
            {"Something", TestSomething}},
    )
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/BC5MG8WXYGD

The error I'm getting is:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4b5948]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, running tests should be done via the `go test` command.

Certain types and functions exported in the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package are for the testing framework, not for you. Quoting from [`testing.RunTests()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#RunTests):

> RunTests is an internal function but exported because it is cross-package; it is part of the implementation of the "go test" command.

It "had" to be exported because it predates "internal" packages.

There. You've been warned.

If you still want to do it, call [`testing.Main()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Main) instead of `testing.RunTests()`.

For example:

```
func TestGood(t *testing.T) {
}

func TestBad(t *testing.T) {
    t.Error("This is a mocked failed test")
}

func main() {
    testing.Main(
        nil,
        []testing.InternalTest{
            {"Good", TestGood},
            {"Bad", TestBad},
        },
        nil, nil,
    )
}
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eAA5icPB9nJ)):

```
--- FAIL: Bad (0.00s)
    prog.go:11: This is a mocked failed test
FAIL
```

If you want to capture the success of the testing, use the "newer" [`testing.MainStart()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#MainStart) function.

First we need a helper type (which implements an unexported interface):

```
type testDeps struct{}

func (td testDeps) MatchString(pat, str string) (bool, error)   { return true, nil }
func (td testDeps) StartCPUProfile(w io.Writer) error           { return nil }
func (td testDeps) StopCPUProfile()                             {}
func (td testDeps) WriteProfileTo(string, io.Writer, int) error { return nil }
func (td testDeps) ImportPath() string                          { return "" }
func (td testDeps) StartTestLog(io.Writer)                      {}
func (td testDeps) StopTestLog() error                          { return nil }
func (td testDeps) SetPanicOnExit0(bool)                        {}
```

And now using it:

```
m := testing.MainStart(testDeps{},
    []testing.InternalTest{
        {"Good", TestGood},
        {"Bad", TestBad},
    },
    nil, nil,
)

result := m.Run()
fmt.Println(result)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EcObC2KBOkP)):

```
--- FAIL: Bad (0.00s)
    prog.go:13: This is a mocked failed test
FAIL
1
```

If all tests pass, `result` will be `0`.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean by "if you want to capture the success of the testing"?

Comment: @ninesalt If you want to know from the main app whether tests passed or failed, e.g. you want to act differently on success.

Comment: Ah okay gotcha.

Comment: Is there any way I can let other tests run if a test before them has paniced? This doesnt seem to be happening

Comment: @ninesalt A testing function shouldn't panic, that's not a normal testing function. You may wrap it in another function (that recovers in case of panics) before adding it to the `[]InternalTest` slice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It seemed great and exactly what I needed, but `MainStart is meant for use by tests generated by 'go test'. It is not meant to be called directly and is not subject to the Go 1 compatibility document. It may change signature from release to release.`

Comment: @MariaEfimenko Yes, exactly as my answer states too. You should run tests using `go test`.

Comment: @icza yes, that's right! Sorry

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to fire a command

```
go test -v -json
```

inside the code through exec.Command, initialise a reader that will read from stdout and then parse the output.

This answer was given by https://github.com/AlekSi
Very grateful, thank you Aleksi!

https://github.com/FerretDB/dance/blob/main/internal/gotest/gotest.go